# InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: Unsupported locator strategy: -custom error with Appium using Selenium ChromeDriver and Chrome

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, appium

I'm trying to run the test.ai plugin for appium (https://github.com/testdotai/appium-classifier-plugin). It has a custom locator strategy. I set up appium (version 1.13.0, also tried downgrading to 1.9.2-beta.2) and did:

```
'npm install -g test-ai-classifier'
```

it was installed, as shown:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwtkt.png

I then wrote a simple test to check if everything is set up correctly:

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileBy;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class TestClass {

    private AppiumDriver driver;
    private By cart = MobileBy.custom("cart");

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "9");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "NB1GAD17B1504154");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");

        HashMap<String, String> customFindModules = new HashMap<>();
        customFindModules.put("ai", "test-ai-classifier");

        capabilities.setCapability("customFindModules", customFindModules);
        capabilities.setCapability("shouldUseCompactResponses", false);

        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown(){

    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod(){
        goToWebsite(driver);
        openCartUseAi(driver);
    }

    public void goToWebsite(AppiumDriver driver){
        driver.get("https://www.ebay.com/");

    }

    public void openCartUseAi(AppiumDriver driver){
        driver.findElement(cart).click();
    }



}
```

This causes the following error when ran:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:/home/piotrek/intellij/ideaIC-2019.1.2/idea-IC-191.7141.44/lib/idea_rt.jar=46303:/home/piotrek/intellij/ideaIC-2019.1.2/idea-IC-191.7141.44/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/piotrek/intellij/ideaIC-2019.1.2/idea-IC-191.7141.44/lib/idea_rt.jar:/home/piotrek/intellij/ideaIC-2019.1.2/idea-IC-191.7141.44/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/home/piotrek/intellij/ideaIC-2019.1.2/idea-IC-191.7141.44/plugins/junit/lib/junit5-rt.jar:/home/piotrek/IdeaProjects/appiumTestMVN/target/test-classes:/home/piotrek/Downloads/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/io/appium/java-client/7.0.0/java-client-7.0.0.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/3.141.59/selenium-java-3.141.59.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-chrome-driver/3.141.59/selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-edge-driver/3.141.59/selenium-edge-driver-3.141.59.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-firefox-driver/3.141.59/selenium-firefox-driver-3.141.59.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-ie-driver/3.141.59/selenium-ie-driver-3.141.59.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-opera-driver/3.141.59/selenium-opera-driver-3.141.59.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-remote-driver/3.141.59/selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-safari-driver/3.141.59/selenium-safari-driver-3.141.59.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.8.15/byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.3/commons-exec-1.3.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/25.0-jre/guava-25.0-jre.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-compat-qual/2.0.0/checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.1.3/error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.1/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/animal-sniffer-annotations/1.14/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.11.0/okhttp-3.11.0.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okio/okio/1.14.0/okio-1.14.0.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-support/3.141.59/selenium-support-3.141.59.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-api/3.141.59/selenium-api-3.141.59.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.6/httpclient-4.5.6.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.10/httpcore-4.4.10.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/cglib/cglib/3.2.8/cglib-3.2.8.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.2.1/asm-6.2.1.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant/1.10.3/ant-1.10.3.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant-launcher/1.10.3/ant-launcher-1.10.3.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.6/commons-validator-1.6.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.2/commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8.1/commons-digester-1.8.1.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.8/commons-lang3-3.8.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.6/commons-io-2.6.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.1.0.RELEASE/spring-context-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.1.0.RELEASE/spring-aop-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.1.0.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.0.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.1.0.RELEASE/spring-jcl-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.1.0.RELEASE/spring-expression-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.1/aspectjweaver-1.9.1.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar:/home/piotrek/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 TestClass,testMethod
Jun 07, 2019 1:43:44 PM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: Unsupported locator strategy: -custom
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.157)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 5.0.0-15-generic x86_64)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'piotrek-VirtualBox', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.0.0-15-generic', java.version: '11.0.3'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {browserName: Chrome, customFindModules: {ai: test-ai-classifier}, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {browserName: Chrome, customFindModules: {ai: test-ai-classifier}, deviceName: NB1GAD17B1504154, platformName: android, platformVersion: 9, shouldUseCompactResponses: false}, deviceManufacturer: HMD Global, deviceModel: TA-1004, deviceName: NB1GAD17B1504154, deviceScreenSize: 1440x2560, deviceUDID: NB1GAD17B1504154, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, platform: LINUX, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 9, shouldUseCompactResponses: false, takesScreenshot: true, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: 6cb83c3b-3405-483a-8dc3-21eec62b4676
*** Element info: {Using=-custom, value=ai:cart}

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:62)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.FindsByCustom.findElementByCustom(FindsByCustom.java:38)
    at TestClass.openCartUseAi(TestClass.java:64)
    at TestClass.testMethod(TestClass.java:49)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? When rewriting this test to not use the plugin, everything works fine, so Appium is set up correctly.

I had a look at this doc, but still can't see what I'm missing: http://appium.io/docs/en/advanced-concepts/element-finding-plugins/

Thank You in advance for your help!

PS not sure if this is relevant, but I'm using an Ubuntu virtual machine for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got this figured out myself. Apparently Appium and Test.Ai don't yet support a custom locator strategy on web apps. This only works on native apps for now. Shame they didn't put this info in their documentation :P

Comment: Thanks, spent lot of time on finding out what mistake I was doing.

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: Unsupported locator strategy: -custom
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session due to an **invalid argument** within an **Unsupported locator strategy**.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.46*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.46*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v71-73**

- You are using *chrome=74.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v74.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/74.0.3729.6/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v74**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.46* and the *Chrome Browser v74.0*

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  [ChromeDriver v75.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=75.0.3770.8/) level.
- Upgrade *Chrome* to *Chrome v75* level. ([as per ChromeDriver v75.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.8/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.

Comment: Thank You for your reply! I updated chromedriver to version 74.0.3729.6 (latest stable release). Chrome stayed in version 74.0.3729.157, as it is the latest available for the device I'm using. This should solve any incompatibility. However I'm still getting the same error. I've updated the post with the latest result

Answer (score 0):

Set this capability,

```
setCapability("chromeOptions", ImmutableMap.of("w3c", false));
```

On my side got the same issue, I was try out this code it worked smoothly.