# How can I fix "Unsupported locator strategy" for XPATH which contains a valid following-sibling path?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I'm using Selenium for Python 3.x and Chrome webdriver. I would like to locate a price element using XPATH expression.
HTML looks:

[image]

My XPATH to this element looks in this way and is valid:

```
//td[contains(text(), 'Montant')]/following-sibling::td/span
```

I can find element by this XPATH in console by

```
$x("//td[contains(text(), 'Montant')]/following-sibling::td/span")
```

ChroPath plugin and XPath helper plugin shows this XPATH as valid too.
But when I run the test I get this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
>   Unsupported locator strategy: //td[contains(text(), 'Sous
>   total')]/following-sibling::td/span   (Session info:
>   chrome=78.0.3904.108)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522
>   (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Linux
>   4.15.0-70-generic x86_64)

I don't know why this XPATH generates this error and how I can fix this. Additionally, another  XPATH axes don't generate the problems.

Comment: Did you check version incompatibility? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491606/invalidargumentexception-invalid-argument-unsupported-locator-strategy-custo

Comment: update chromedriver version to compatible with chrome browser version

Comment: What code are you using to find the element? The issue might be with the way you are calling `driver.FindElement`, and not have anything to do with the XPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this working ?

```
'//td[contains(text(), 'Montant')]/../td[2]/span'
```

Comment: @Alejandro: have you tested yourself ?

Comment: Your expression goes back to the parent and selects every child. It's not the same as selecting a child and from then selecting following siblings. Yours also selects the mark and preceding siblings.

Comment: XPath is 1-indexed, I think you'll need `td[2]`

Comment: I found what was the reason of this error. I thought that this was xpath fault because in the console I got an error about wrong selector but the issue was quite different. I was wanted to perform `selenium text ` function on this element to get a string from the element and this generates this error. When I used get_attribute('textContent') method it works correctly. I don't know why actually it works in this way, but there was the issue;)